# Dataset Transposing

Tags: sql, unpivot

I am trying to create a table in SQL that lists the current column heading with the existing row so current listing would have heading 
[current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqB1r.png)

```
Code   1   2    3
ABC    50  80  90
DEF    40  20  70
```

but i want to show the value as 
[Target Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkpE.png)

```
ABC 1 50
ABC 2 80
ABC 3 90
DEF 1 40
DEF 2 20
DEF 3 70
```

Not even sure if it is possible but would appreciate assistance

Comment: What's stopping you from creating a table with `code`, `number` and `value`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select code, 1, col1 from t union all
select code, 2, col2 from t union all
select code, 3, col3 from t ;
```

Some databases support lateral joins, which are more efficient than `union all`.